# Share Internet in LAN through dongle

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

I've one Mi-Fi data dongle ([Tata Photon Wiz Wi-Fi](http://www.tataphoton.com/photon-whiz.aspx)) for an Internet connection, [Netgear Wireless-N300 Modem Router](http://www.netgear.com/home/products/networking/dsl-modems-routers/dgn2200.aspx), Printer, Iomega iConnect, a couple of computers (Ubuntu)/MacBook Pro, and mobiles/tablets. What I want to do is all computer/phone/laptop can share data, printer, and shared drive through LAN and can access internet connection by my Mi-Fi data dongle.

It’s very simple in case of Tata Photon, as my router has a USB drive make it simple. But my router doesn’t have Tata Photon Wiz Wi-Fi (EC315) in it’s (DGN2200M) firmware. So I'm looking for other ways to handle this situation.

Is it possible to share internet in LAN, if I login to any of my computer/laptop and use dongle via USB of my computer/laptop? If it's possible to get access to Internet directly to my router through Wi-Fi of my dongle without login to any machine that’d be great.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to use your Tata Photon Wiz Wi-Fi dongle with is a 3G Mi-Fi device with the Netgear N300 router to share the Internet connectivity the Tata Photon Wiz Wi-Fi dongle provides? From what I can see I do not think that is possible. The router itself would need to know how to communicate with the USB Mi-Fi dongle. And not many off-the-shelf routers can handle that.

But a few low-cost routers from TP-Link explicitly do provide USB Mi-Fi connections:

- [**TP-LINK TL-MR3020**](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16833704127&cm_re=3G_ROuter-_-33-704-127-_-Product): 3G/4G Wireless N150 Portable Router, Pocket Design, Multifunction, 150Mbps
- [**TP-LINK TL-MR3040**](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16833704138&cm_re=3G_ROuter-_-33-704-138-_-Product): 3G/4G Wireless N150 Portable Router, Internal Battery, Pocket Design, Multifunction, 150Mbps

There are even some cheaper seemingly “no name” brands that claim to support similar functionality, but from what I can see TP-Link seems to have a nice—and well supported—niche market for these types of devices.